# How to connect websocket after set up with NGINX and Supervisor?

Tags: django, sockets, websocket, django-channels, channel

I created a Django Channel beside my wsgi application. Everything works fine if I run:

```
daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 myapp.asgi:application
```

I can connect to the websocekt but after I created supervisor with nginx I can not connect and I don't see any useful log that could solve the problem.

When I check the supervisor status it has no error:

```
asgi:asgi0                       RUNNING   pid 23981, uptime 0:10:22
asgi:asgi1                       RUNNING   pid 23980, uptime 0:10:22
asgi:asgi2                       RUNNING   pid 23983, uptime 0:10:22
asgi:asgi3                       RUNNING   pid 23982, uptime 0:10:22
```

The socket was originally localhost:8001 and I also allowed UFW to use that port but it didn't work so I changed to my server IP.

**Supervisor**

```
[fcgi-program:asgi]
# TCP socket used by Nginx backend upstream
socket=tcp://139.162.172.87:8001

# Directory where your site's project files are located
directory=/home/markkiraly/crumb_backend

# Each process needs to have a separate socket file, so we use process_num
# Make sure to update "mysite.asgi" to match your project name
command=/home/markkiraly/crumb_backend/venv/bin/daphne --fd 0 --access-log - --proxy-headers crumb_backend.asgi:application
# Number of processes to startup, roughly the number of CPUs you have
numprocs=4

# Give each process a unique name so they can be told apart
process_name=asgi%(process_num)d

# Automatically start and recover processes
autostart=true
autorestart=true

# Choose where you want your log to go
stdout_logfile=/var/log/asgi.log
redirect_stderr=true
```

**NGINX CONFIG**

```
upstream channels-backend {
    server 139.162.172.87:8001;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name crumbliterature.com www.crumbliterature.com;
    location /static/ {
        root /home/markkiraly/crumb_backend/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /home/markkiraly/crumb_backend/;
    }

     location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }

     location /ws/ {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
        proxy_pass http://channels-backend;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

}
```

I tried to connect every possible way:

```
ws://139.162.172.87/ws/chat/1/
ws://139.162.172.87:8001/ws/chat/1/
ws://crumbliterature.com/ws/chat/1/
ws://crumbliterature.com:8001/ws/chat/1/
```

Answer (score 0):

1)

If NGINX and Django Channel is located on one machine, then you can replace

```
upstream channels-backend {
    server 139.162.172.87:8001;
}
```

with

```
upstream channels-backend {
    server localhost:8001;
}
```

2)

I don't know about Django Channels but some application can try different ports if the default or selected is blocked by another app. May be your apps works but with another port or got stuck but do not inform about it. Try to check which application listens on 8001 (if one listens)